# Simple question, value not being display in DevExpress's LookupComboBox

Tags: delphi, devexpress

This is a Delphi project, but I suspect DevExpress's component works similar for Delphi and .NET.

I have a DevExpress GridDBTableView, when selecting a cell in one of the column, I want a LookupComboBox to show up, where user can select an item, and the value gets display in the table cell. Simple.

- I've set the column's Properties set to 'LookupComboBox'.
- I have ListColumns setup with 'LocationName' and 'QuantityOnHand'.
- ListSource is set to a datasource that's linked a dataset of 'LocationID', 'LocationName', and 'QuantityOnhand'.
- ListFieldNames is set to 'LocationName;QuantityOnHand'

When I click on the cell, the combo box shows up with locations for me to choose, but when I choose a location, the table cell doesn't show the location name. In fact, I can't type anything in the cell.

What am I missing?

Ideally, I would like to be able to select a location from the combo box, the location name shows up in the table cell, and I can somehow store the corresponding LocationID that was selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should also set the column's Properties.KeyFieldName property to the KeyField of the Lookup DataSource.  In this case, everything should work properly.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I found as well in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, all the answer is in the Express Editors' help file article 'Using Lookup Editors'.

The only step I missed was setting the LookupComboBox's KeyFieldNames property to 'LocationID'.